# Magento 2 paypal Instant Payment Notification (IPN) URL

Tags: magento2, payment-methods, paypal, payment-gateway, ipn

Can anyone tell me what is the Correct **Paypal Instant Payment Notification (IPN)** url for Magento 2.x. I have used

> **BASE_URL/index.php/paypal/ipn/index/**

and

> **YOUR_BASE_URL/paypal/ipn/**

Both URLs get **500 Error** in Post method.

Comment: Did you test in sandbox mode? If not then try it in sandbox first.

Answer (score 3):

If someone else comes across this problem: I've had the exact same issue and found out, that the configuration was wrong. 
My exception.log had lines, containing this error message:

> [2019-07-23 07:23:35] main.CRITICAL: The requested
>   "requested_email@domain.com" and the configured
>   "configured_email@domain.com" merchant emails don't match.
>   {"exception":"[object] (Exception(code: 0): The requested
>   \"requested_email@domain.com\" and the configured
>   \"configured_email@domain.com\" merchant emails don't match. at
>   /var/www/magento/htdocs/vendor/magento/module-paypal/Model/Ipn.php:120)"}
>   []

I had to reconfigure the PayPal payment settings to provide the correct email address: Now the error is gone.

Answer (score 2):

The comment from Anime is partially incorrect. You don't need to set the IPN URL in your PayPal account. It actually doesn't matter as the request from your Magento shop will override anything that you set in the account. However, if you set it in PayPal and you have, for example, an eBay shop, that will cause that the IPNs eventually become disabled in PayPal.

Are you getting http error 500 from PayPal or from your service?
Also, did you contact PayPal support to know what error are they getting from your system?

In order to know the problem, you first need to contact PayPal support and ask them for the IPN http response that they are getting. That will give you the best indication about how to continue.

Comment: i have contact papal and the also said my IPN url get 500 error and i have to fix that.